# Character controller dash unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to implement dashing mechanic but every time I am trying to run this code my unity freezes. Any solutuions?

```
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)){

        StartCoroutine(DashCorutine());
        
    }

    }  
 private IEnumerator DashCorutine()
{
    float starttime = Time.time;
    while(starttime + dashTime > Time.time){
     Vector3 moveDerection= transform.forward*dashlength;

     controller.Move(moveDerection *Time.deltaTime*dashSpeed);
    }



    yield return null;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `yield` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `yield break` inside while loop

```
private IEnumerator DashCorutine()
{
    float startTime = Time.time;
    while (startTime + dashTime > Time.time)
    {
         Vector3 moveDirection = transform.forward * dashLength;
         controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime * dashSpeed);
         yield break;
    }
}
```

Also check out coding standards for better code quality.

And fix the typos.

[Coding Standards](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13QZjY4Fyg8m8IT09wvCvrBt3X6ra5IpGPUOxpyy5DPw/edit)